# Angular 6 - run javascript method outside the app

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 6 app which will be embed inside another application. That application injects javascript to the browser in order to expose certain functionalities to the angular app.

As an example, when i run my angular app inside the mentioned application, if i go to the web console, i can execute the following js method

```
API.callService("Special Service");
```

and works fine.

How can i execute the same inside the angular app ?

i tried the following in the component

```
declare var API: any;
```

and then at ngAfterViewInit() method

```
API.callService("Special Service");
```

but i get an error as API is undefined.

As extra information, i can use the chrome dev tools for the embed browser. If i want to run the javascript method i just do..

[image]

And that works fine ! The issue is to do the same call from the Angular component.

[image: This is what i see when calling from the component]
Any idea how to solve it ?

Thanks!

Comment: what is this API object which you are calling ?

Comment: it is a javascript API object injected by the shell app that embed the angular app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

I found the issue

Despite of the fact i was calling the api in the ngAfterViewInit, it seems that the api was not available.

i tried with

setTimeout(()=>this.click(), 1000);

```
 click(){
var result = SrwOSGiApi.callOSGIService("com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.base.IAgentProfileService","getPcc", null);
```

}

and works fine !!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you

```
declare var API: any;
```

You are saying API as any value, so you get undefined;

Try on your constructor or ngAfterViewInit

```
this.API = API.callService("Special Service");
```

Comment: Hi david, if i do that it wont work. if i need to do this.API, API should be an attribute of the component class. If i call both the same, the issue is that when trying to assign the API.callService result to the component attribute, it will fail, as API is still undefined (in that case API != this.API)

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your javascript functions, then you can require them in your angular module.

Of course, you'll need to be able or have the right to modify the original javascript file to add the module exports declarations.

To use the 'require' function in an angular component, you'll need to run :

`$ npm install @types/node`

Then in tsconfig.json, under the "typeRoots" property, add :

`"types": ["node"],`

Here is a quick example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qphccu

Comment: I tried a similar approach, it does work when doing an alert, but not when you are trying to execute the injected function

Comment: I've edited the original post with more information about the issue

Comment: Well, normally, if it works for an alert, it should work for more, am I wrong ? Everything depend on the way you export the injected functions and the data going with it.